# I have added slash to end of link. CSS is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

My website is asp.net.

I have added `/` to the end of my link, like this:

```
http://localhost:5022/Registration.aspx/
```

Why does this not work in CSS?

Comment: without slash all css proper work but add last link slash not work css

Comment: Isn't "Registration.aspx" the name of a file? Then don't use a slash. Only use slashes after directories.

Comment: Why would you add a folder marker to the end of a file name? Explain why you are doing this apparently silly thing that you have proven to yourself doesn't work? What are you trying to achieve? What are you thinking?

Comment: all characters work fine but only issue is slash charater

Comment: I've removed the `php` tag as your question relates to ASP .Net. Unnecessary tags distracts the answerers.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<base href="base link" />
```

This will set the base URL of links and images (basically everything). This will fix the links.

Example:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to point out that to use the base tag it must go in the head of a site...so example below..

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.whatever.com/images/">
</head>
```